# AbstractMethodError during Spring project build

Tags: hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

AbstractMethodError is happening during spring maven build in Spring framework.

Using:

- spring4.3.0.RELEASE
- hibernate5.0.3.Final
- hibernate-search5.2.1.Final

**This is my part of pom.xml:**

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <hibernate-version>5.0.3.Final</hibernate-version>
    <hibernate-search.version>5.2.1.Final</hibernate-search.version>
    <hibernate-entitymanager.version>5.0.6.Final</hibernate-entitymanager.version>
    <hibernate-validator.version>5.2.4.Final</hibernate-validator.version>
    <javax-el.version>2.2.4</javax-el.version>
    <hibernate-Beta1-version>5.0.0.Beta1</hibernate-Beta1-version>
    <spring-version>4.3.0.RELEASE</spring-version>

    <slf4j-version>1.7.21</slf4j-version>
    <log4j-version>1.2.17</log4j-version>
    <mysql-version>5.1.39</mysql-version>
    <druid.version>1.0.20</druid.version>
    <aspectj-version>1.8.9</aspectj-version>
    <guava.version>19.0</guava.version>
    <poi.version>3.14</poi.version>
    <jackson.version>2.7.5</jackson.version>
    <commons-fileupload.version>1.3</commons-fileupload.version>
    <ckfinder-version>2.3</ckfinder-version>

    <lucene.version>3.6.2</lucene.version>
```

**Error stacktrace:**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/yunlian/project/cloudsLotus/51itspace/admin/target/admin/WEB-INF/lib/common-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/spring-hibernate.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:187)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1048)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1018)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:570)
... 88 more
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:278)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:504)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:488)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
... 99 more
```

Comment: You should not just paste an error log here, try to describe what you were trying to do and in what situation.

Comment: Please frame your questions properly. There should be some content to explain your question.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, hibernate jar is not available in the classpath of your application. Check whether hibernate added as dependency in your pom.xml like below.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I want to use hibernate5